# Chrome APIs without calling chrome.app.window.create()

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to use chrome APIs (specially chrome.sockets) inside its background script without calling chrome.app.window.create()?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it is possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, and I've done it many times. There is no requirement whatsoever for a window. One of my apps that does this listens for a message from Google Cloud Messaging and puts a notification on the screen when it arrives. (Using a bunch of Chrome App APIs.) When no messages are arriving, it goes into an inactive state.

Comment: Could you please mention what type of socket you have used?

Comment: Just want to expand on that last point: without an open window, your background script will likely go into an inactive state.  It may work for a bit, but won't be guaranteed.  For this reason, you can setup event handlers (onInstalled, onStartup, tcpServer receive, notification clicked, gcm message arrival, etc..), and do work in the handlers, but shouldn't expect to just do background processing forever.

Comment: Definitely all work in the background script should be in handlers. When the app goes inactive, all code is discarded, but not the fact that some handlers were set.Then, when an event associated with a handler occurs, the background script is reloaded, re-setting the handlers, and then the handler for the event that occurred is executed. Any code in the background script NOT in a handler (e.g, code to set handlers, and other miscellaneous code) is executed when the background script is loaded. As this occurs at effectively random times, it's not a good place to do anything EXCEPT set handlers.

Comment: I've used the chrome.sockets.tcp API in background scripts. Really, there are no limitations, except that any APIs that manipulate a window can't be used unless there actually is a window.